# Why Advices methods are not getting call?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Spring 4 + AspectJ

Hi Folks,

I am new to spring and AOP i am just learning by doing hands on. here i want to externalize the cross-cutting concerns which are in Audience class. but while executing the test class i am just getting output without cross-cutting concern methods body.

i am unable to figure out why these methods are not executing please anyone can look into the code. Thanks.

**Output :**

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
CircusPerformar is performing
```

This is an interface which is having one method perform.

1) Performer.java

```
package concert;

public interface Performer {
    void perform();
}
```

2) CircusPerformar.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class CircusPerformar implements Performer{

        @Override
        public void perform() {
            System.out.println("CircusPerformar is performing");
        }
    }
```

3) PerformanceConfig.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

    @Configuration
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
    @ComponentScan
    public class PerformanceConfig {

    }
```

5) Audience.java

```
package concert;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class Audience {

    @Before("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void silenceCellPhones(){
        System.out.println("Silencing the phone");
    }

    @Before("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..)")
    public void takeSeats(){
        System.out.println("Taking seat");
    }

    @AfterReturning("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..))")
    public void applause(){
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP CLAP!!!!");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("execution(** concert.Performance.perform(..)")
    public void demandMoney(){
        System.out.println("Demanding a refund");
    }

}
```

6) PerformanceTest.java

```
package concert;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class PerformanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(PerformanceConfig.class);
        ctx.refresh();
        Performer cp = (CircusPerformar) ctx.getBean("circusPerformar");
        cp.perform();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a bean for your aspect, so the aspect doesn't exists, so nothing will get AOP applied. Solution add the aspect as a bean to your configuration.

Comment: Hey Deinum, i edited the configuration file, added @ComponentScan annotation. Still i am getting same output.

Comment: The component scan won't help as your aspect isn't a `@Component` so it will never be detected.